# javascript. можно ли код сделать более логичным?

Tags: javascript

```
function ch(obj, tag) {
            var ch = obj.childNodes;
            var res = [];
            if(tag) {
                    for (var i=0; i < ch.length; i++) {
                            if (ch[i].nodeType === 1 && ch[i].tagName.toLowerCase === tag.toLowerCase) {
                                    res[res.length] = ch[i];
                            }
                    }
            } else {
                    for (var i=0; i < ch.length; i++) {
                            if (ch[i].nodeType === 1) {
                                    res[res.length] = ch[i];
                            }
                    }
            }

            return res;
    }
```

функция возвращает либо всех прямых потомков, либо только определенного тега.
не нравится проверка на существование переменной и два цикла внутри.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9BzsRi4b

Comment: А приведите пример работы? У меня вот такой код на данной странице не работает `ch(document.getElementById('room'))`, хотя `document.getElementById('room').childNodes` отдает массив элементов.

Comment: Zhukov Roman, поравил ошибку. было i > ch.length

Comment: Замените

    ch[i].nodeType === 1

на

    var child = ch[i];
    child.nodeType === child.ELEMENT_NODE

В остальном не вижу никаких проблем

Comment: короче, кто и как бы написал функцию, которая на основе параметров выдает список прямых потомков?


    ch(obj,{'tagName':'div','className':'class'})


примерно так

короче, если вместо tag будет бесконечное количество аргументов, то как их все проверить?

Comment: @Heleg в читабельности, в вашем примере абсолютно неясно что это за "магическое число" ( если не знаешь, конечно )

Comment: @AlexWindHope понял, святой эксплорер не понимает циферки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы вынес условия в подфункции. Мне кажется, вы и сами толком не понимаете, что делает ваш код:

```
function findValidNodes (node, tagName) {
    var children, result, i, l;

    children = node.childNodes;
    result = [];

    for (i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (isValidTagName( tagName, children[i] )) {
            result.push( children[i] );
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function isValidTagName (tagName, node) {
    if (node.nodeType !== node.ELEMENT_NODE) return false;

    return tagName == null || isTagName(node, tagName);
}

function isTagName (node, tagName) {
    return node.tagName.toLowerCase() === tagName.toLowerCase();
}
```

Как только функции были вынесены с вменяемыми названиями переменных можно заметить, что прояснилась и структура.

А теперь можно сократить при помощи метода [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
function findValidNodes (node, tagName) {
    return [].slice.call(node.childNodes)
        .filter( isValidTag.bind( null, tagName ) );
}
```

**UPD:**

Я вижу у вас дополнительная просьба:

> короче, кто и как бы написал функцию,
> которая на основе параметров выдает
> список прямых потомков?
>
> ```
> ch(obj,{'tagName':'div','className':'class'})
> ```
>
> примерно так короче, если вместо tag
> будет бесконечное количество
> аргументов, то как их все проверить?

Теперь просто меняем `isValidTagName` - подставляем проверку на условия:

```
function isValidTag (conditions, node) {
    if (node.nodeType != node.ELEMENT_NODE) return false;
    if (conditions == null) return true;

    for (var i in conditions) {
        if (node[i].toLowerCase() != conditions[i].toLowerCase()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ch(obj, tag, u) { 
    for(var re=[], i=0, nodes = obj.childNodes; i < nodes.length; i++) (tag!=u && tag.toUpperCase()==nodes[i].tagName)?re.push(nodes[i]):(tag==u)?re.push(nodes[i]):null;
    return re;
}

console.log(ch(document.getElementById('element'), 'input'));
```

Такие вот дела: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zwE1zdeL

Подробней:

```
function check(obj, tag) {
    var return_values = [];
    var child_nodes = obj.childNodes;

    for(var i = 0; i < child_nodes.length; i++) {
        if(tag == undefined) {
            return_values.push(child_nodes[i]);
        }
        else {
            if(tag.toUpperCase() == child_nodes[i].tagName) {
                return_values.push(child_nodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @lampa: не забывайте, что @Heleg нужны были ноды с nodeType === 3.

Comment: @Zhukov Roman я хотел, чтобы ТС сам до этого додумался :) По этому кстати добавил расширенный ответ.

Comment: @lampa: я если честно, не понял, зачем нужен аргумент u в первом коде. а во втором, если не указать тег, push запихнет все childNodes, включая и текстовые, если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: @Heleg аргумент u будет приравниваться к undefined, сокращенная версия :) Не ошибаетесь :) Добавьте проверки по вкусу.

Comment: ну в таком случае ничего не изменилось, просто теперь всё внутри тернарного оператора. не холивара ради, но я противник такого стиля кода, сильно ограничивает читаемость, а на производительность никак не сказывается. а с u - очень оригинально, кстати, не додумался, что она делает. от системы проверка -> цикл тут никак не избавиться?

Comment: @lampa,

     tag == undefined

это плохой способ сравнения, не стоит его использовать, особенно в цикле.

Comment: @AlexWindHope да, всё очень плохо :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, чем же это плохо?

Comment: Этот код:

    tag == undefined

Я вообще считаю, что все такие проверки надо писать только так:

    tag == null

Короче, работает так же, логически корректно, null не переопределяется.

Comment: Если нужно проверить на undefined, то нужно использовать строгое равенство e.g. `===`, если же просто на "ложное" значение - достаточно просто `if( tag ) {}`

Comment: @AlexWindHope, вы так же заблуждаетесь, как большинство "любителей" JS, которые перешли на него с php. Дело в том, что в php сравнение с null действительно проверяет на false:

    shock@notebook:~$ php -r "var_dump(false == null);"
    bool(true)

И, по сути `if ($var == null)` равносильно `if (!$var)`

Comment: JavaScript же отличается от php поведением. `== null` проверяет только на `undefined` и `null`, а `false`, `0` и `''` под это сравнение не подпадают.

    shock@notebook:~$ node -e "console.log(false == null)"
    false

Так что вы ошибаетесь. Если хотите проверить на неопределённость, то самый логичный вариант будет проверять на `== null`, именно так, с двумя равно, т.к. он проверяет `null`, `undefined` и ничего больше.

Проверка с `if (foo)` захватывает и другие пустые значения, такие как `false`, `0` и `''`

Comment: @Shock, на мой взгляд, в этом случае и ноль и пустая строка не должны попадать в if.

По поводу неопределенности - null не есть undefined :)

Comment: По-моему с точки зрения логики null и undefined должны нести один смысл. Именно для этого в стандарте их и приравняли.

Посмотрите код JQuery, MooTools, AtomJS. Очень часто используется конструкция `== null`.

Как раз 0 и пустая строка - это вполне опредёлнные значения. Чем они хуже единицы или строки из трёх символов?

Comment: @Shock - нет желания спорить